# How to concatenate inputs of two charfields and store the result in another model in django?

Tags: python, django

This is my models.py.Here I want to create a username field such that it is concatenation of first name and registration ID of the users

For Example:

Let's supose this values:

```
FirstName = Harry
RegistrationID = 32pzc12
```

Then, this is the expected content:

```
Username=Harry_32pzc12
```

The current `User` model:

```
class User(models.Model):
 
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    LastName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    RegistrationID = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    EmailID = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    Password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ProfilePicture = models.ImageField()
    MobileNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    DateOfBirth = models.DateField()
    UserType = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=UserTypeOptions)
    Description = models.TextField()
```

Comment: Your post is not a question. Remember to explain where is the issue and what did you try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 **override** the **save method** of the model,

```
class User(models.Model): 

FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
LastName = models.CharField(max_length=20)
RegistrationID = models.CharField(max_length=6)
EmailID = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
Password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
ProfilePicture = models.ImageField()
MobileNumber = models.CharField(max_length=10)
DateOfBirth = models.DateField()
UserType = models.CharField(max_length=10,choices=UserTypeOptions)
Description = models.TextField()

def save(self, *args , **kwargs):
    self.username = str(self.firstname) + str(self.RegistrationID)
    super().save(*args , **kwargs)
```

**official documentation :**
[Model save method official documantation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/)

**OR**

2 If you use a custom forms , and **create the object from views** on POSTing of the Form,

```
def view(request):
    if request.method == POST:
        firstname = request.POST.get('firstname')
        RegistrationID = request.POST.get('RegistrationID')
        #other elements from the form
        username = str(firstname) + str(RegistrationID)
        
        instance = User.objects.create(username = username , other similar parameters, ..)
        return render('request' , somehtml)
    else:
        #GET method content
        #display the form
```